# How to enable Silverlight on Chrome 39 or newer

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, moonlight

I know, that this question was asked and answered too many times, but I tried almost everything and nothing seems to work in any version newer than 39 of Chrome.

Pipelight doesn't seem to work since Chrome removed NPAPI support in version 35, Moonlight was abandoned long time ago and Silverlight running in Wine is not what I need. Could anybody help me to run Silverlight plugin please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work in Chrome in Linux,   but there are two other ways.

The first is the easiest: switch to another browser which pipelight supports, like Firefox.

The second is somewhat harder and requires a (legal) copy of Windows. You can put Windows inside a virtual box or dual boot it. On the Internet are many tutorials which explains how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know these possibilities, if there will be no other way, I'll just install another browser. I hoped there is some workaround or so.